# Move items and read values from QTableWidget with spinbox widget (PyQt5)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I have a software tool that has a table filled with two columns: parameter and precision. Some parameters in the "Precision" column have spinbox widget and some parameters have just text "N/A".
I have two questions:

1. How to move the rows in a table up and down including the spinbox widget. Currently I was able to move only the parameter name and the spinbox disappears as soon as I try to move row up or down.
   Below is the code with functions defining the move of selected row up or down:
   '''

   ```
    def _buttonMoveUpClicked(self):
        rowIndex = self.table.currentRow()
        self.table.insertRow(rowIndex - 1)
        for i in range(self.table.columnCount()):
            self.table.setItem(rowIndex - 1, i, self.table.takeItem(rowIndex + 1, i))
            self.table.selectRow(rowIndex - 1)
        self.table.removeRow(rowIndex + 1)

    def _buttonMoveDownClicked(self):
        rowIndex = self.table.currentRow()
        self.table.insertRow(rowIndex + 2)
        for i in range(self.table.columnCount()):
            self.table.setItem(rowIndex + 2, i,
                               self.table.takeItem(rowIndex, i))
            self.table.selectRow(rowIndex + 2)
        self.table.removeRow(rowIndex)
   ```

'''

2. I need to save the values from table to the lists. How to read the values from the cells with spinbox widget?
   The way how I'm trying to save it now:

'''

```
def _readTable(self):
        list_Parameters = []
        list_Precision = []
        print('1')
        for i in range(self.table.rowCount()):
            print(self.table.item(i, 0).text())
            list_Parameters.append(self.table.item(i, 0).text())
            list_Precision.append(self.table.item(i, 1).text())
```

'''
This is the full code for the software tool:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import pandas as pd

class Window(QWidget):
    singleton: 'Window' = None

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Software tool")
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 1800, 900)
        self.mainLayout=QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)
        self.UI()

    def UI(self):
        self.sublayouts = {}
        self.buttons = {}
        self._view()
        self._fillListWidget()
        self.table.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(self._updateButtonStatus)
        self.buttons['Up'].clicked.connect(self._buttonMoveUpClicked)
        self.buttons['Down'].clicked.connect(self._buttonMoveDownClicked)
        self.show()

    def _view(self):
        self.table = QTableWidget(0, 2)
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Parameter', 'Precision'])
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(1, QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.table.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.table.setEditTriggers(QTableWidget.NoEditTriggers)
        self.buttons['Up'] = QPushButton('&Up')
        self.buttons['Down'] = QPushButton('&Down')

        self.sublayouts['table'] = QGridLayout()
        self.sublayouts['table'].addWidget(self.table, 1, 0, 4, 4)
        self.sublayouts['table'].setRowStretch(4, 1)
        self.sublayouts['table'].addWidget(self.buttons['Up'], 1, 4, 1, 1, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.sublayouts['table'].addWidget(self.buttons['Down'], 2, 4, 1, 1, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)

        self.mainLayout.addLayout(self.sublayouts['table'])

    def _fillListWidget(self):
        list = {
            'Parameters': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
            'Precision': [-1, -1, 2, 3, 1]}
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(list)
        for row in zip(*self.df.to_dict('list').values()):
            itemColumn = QTableWidgetItem(
                row[self.df.columns.get_loc("Parameters")])
            rowPosition = self.table.rowCount()
            self.table.insertRow(rowPosition)
            itemTable = self._tableCell(row[self.df.columns.get_loc("Parameters")])
            self.table.setItem(rowPosition, 0, itemTable)
            df_tmp = self.df[self.df['Parameters'] == row[self.df.columns.get_loc("Parameters")]]
            if df_tmp['Precision'].values[0] >= 0:
                self.spinBox = QSpinBox()
                self.spinBox.setValue(df_tmp['Precision'].values[0])
                self.table.setCellWidget(rowPosition, 1, self.spinBox)
            else:
                itemTable = self._tableCell('N/A')
                self.table.setItem(rowPosition, 1, itemTable)

    def _updateButtonStatus(self):
        self.buttons['Up'].setDisabled(not bool(self.table.selectedItems()) or self.table.rowCount() == 0 or self.table.currentRow()==0)
        self.buttons['Down'].setDisabled(not bool(self.table.selectedItems()) or self.table.rowCount() == 0 or self.table.currentRow()==self.table.rowCount()-1)
        # self._readTable()

    def _buttonMoveUpClicked(self):
        rowIndex = self.table.currentRow()
        self.table.insertRow(rowIndex - 1)
        for i in range(self.table.columnCount()):
            self.table.setItem(rowIndex - 1, i, self.table.takeItem(rowIndex + 1, i))
            self.table.selectRow(rowIndex - 1)
        self.table.removeRow(rowIndex + 1)

    def _buttonMoveDownClicked(self):
        rowIndex = self.table.currentRow()
        self.table.insertRow(rowIndex + 2)
        for i in range(self.table.columnCount()):
            self.table.setItem(rowIndex + 2, i,
                               self.table.takeItem(rowIndex, i))
            self.table.selectRow(rowIndex + 2)
        self.table.removeRow(rowIndex)

    def _tableCell(self, text):
        item = QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setText(text)
        return item

    def _readTable(self):
        list_Parameters = []
        list_Precision = []
        print('1')
        for i in range(self.table.rowCount()):
            print(self.table.item(i, 0).text())
            list_Parameters.append(self.table.item(i, 0).text())
            list_Precision.append(self.table.item(i, 1).text())

def main():
  App=QApplication(sys.argv)
  window =Window()
  sys.exit(App.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly do that with QTableWidget, as it is an higher level widget that doesn't implement index movements in its model.

A *proper* solution would be to create a QAbstractTableItem subclass that would also implement [`moveRows()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#moveRows).

A simpler alternative is available, but remember that model views should always keep track of indexes, and deleting/adding rows won't allow it. If you want to do a *good* implementation, an item model subclass is mandatory.

The alternative comes from the fact that whenever rows (or columns) are removed, their *editors* are destroyed too, and there's very little you can do with it.
Assuming that you *always* want to move *only one row*, the solution is to get the current editor (and its value), delete the row, insert the new one, and create a new editor for it with the previously read value.

For simplicity reasons (and following OOP patterns), I created a common function that accepts the current row and a "delta" argument that tells it if the row has to be "moved" up or down.

```py
def _moveRow(self, row, delta):
    colIndex = self.table.currentColumn()
    items = [self.table.takeItem(row, c) for c in range(self.table.columnCount())]
    oldSpinBox = self.table.cellWidget(row, 1)
    self.table.removeRow(row)
    newRow = row + delta
    self.table.insertRow(newRow)
    for i, item in enumerate(items):
        self.table.setItem(newRow, i, item)
    if isinstance(oldSpinBox, QAbstractSpinBox):
        newSpinBox = QSpinBox()
        newSpinBox.setValue(oldSpinBox.value())
        self.table.setCellWidget(newRow, 1, newSpinBox)
    if colIndex >= 0:
        self.table.setCurrentCell(newRow, colIndex)

def _buttonMoveUpClicked(self):
    rowIndex = self.table.currentRow()
    if rowIndex > 0:
        self._moveRow(rowIndex, -1)

def _buttonMoveDownClicked(self):
    rowIndex = self.table.currentRow()
    if rowIndex < self.table.rowCount() - 1:
        self._moveRow(rowIndex, 1)
```

As said, this is a very simplistic solution, and only works for hardcoded row/column widgets. A more correct and aware solution is to create a subclass of QAbstractTableModel and implement the `moveRows()` function: doing this allows a more proper implementation, will provide the correct editors (so that no `setCellWidget()` would be required) and will allow more correct row movements.

Comment: Thank you very much for such detailed explanation! In my case the suggested solution is working and it's solves the problem!